# Как правильно подключить библиотеку классов к проекту на ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Помогите разобраться, есть простой проект на ASP.NET CORE MVC (ASP.NET CORE 3.1), к нему я создал библиотеку классов (Class Library), добавил внутрь папку Controllers, добавил внутрь файл `HomeController`  с приведенным ниже кодом:

```
[HttpGet]
class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Добавил файл `Startup`, файл View - `Get`, но когда я обращаюсь из основного приложения по адресу `Home/Get` получаю ошибку 404 (причем основное приложение развернуто на IIS и в нем нет похожего пути), кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как решали? Или я что-то не правильно сделал, может кто-нибудь сможет дать ссылку где подробно расписан данный процесс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно в конфигурации (Startup.cs) добавить ваш ClassLib как часть контроллеров.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddControllers() 
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(ClassLib.HomeController).Assembly);
    ....
}
```